# How to combine strings line by line into a single vector in R?

Tags: r

Suppose that we have 3 vectors:

```
a <- c("example1a","example2a","example3a")
b <- c("example1b","example2b")
c <- c("example1c","example2c","example3c","example4c")
```

I want to combine them as follows:

```
[1] "example1a"

[2] "example2a"

[3] "example3a"

[4] "example1b"

...
```

I tried those c(), paste(), str_c() functions but didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have variable names `a`, `b` and `c` in your global environment, maybe the code below is what you want

```
unlist(mget(ls()))
```

such that

```
> unlist(mget(ls()))
         a1          a2          a3          b1          b2 
"example1a" "example2a" "example3a" "example1b" "example2b" 
         c1          c2          c3          c4 
"example1c" "example2c" "example3c" "example4c"
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you @ThomaslsCoding